# Excel creating macros that work on multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am new to Excel Macro and i was given the task with the following excel data

```
Date        Brazil  Turkey  Italy   Panama  Lithuania
3/15/2014   110     47      192     0       2
3/16/2014   118     54      179     0       7
3/17/2014   72      22      96      0       1
3/18/2014   17      20      60      2       2
3/19/2014   19      17      57      0       1
3/20/2014   15      21      52      0       2
```

I am to create a Macro so the  ending result for each Date like such.I have looked up various of ways to do it, but cant seem to find a way. Thank you very much

```
Date        Country             Downloads
3/15/2014   Brazil              110
3/15/2014   Turkey              47
3/15/2014   Italy               192
3/15/2014   Czech Republic      19
3/15/2014   Panama              0
3/15/2014   Lithuania           2
3/15/2014   Costa Rica          6
3/15/2014   Luxembourg          1
```

I tried using just regular Excel interface commands, but found out it will not work and i dont know where to begin with VBA.

```
Range("B9:F10").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
Range("W51").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
Range("A10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range("V51").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("V51").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3/15/2014"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("V51:V55"), Type:=xlFillCopy
Range("V51:V55").Select
Range("Y49").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: show us please your attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/tag/unpivot/  has a few different approaches

Comment: I know you said you wanted a macro and you couldn't get worksheet functions working but if you put the original data in A1:F7 and put the the date and country of the result in A9:A38 and B9:B38 respectively then in C9:C38 you could put `=VLOOKUP(A9,$A$2:$F$7,MATCH(B9,$B$1:$F$1,0)+1)`

Comment: Did the code below work?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting application here -- as Tim's link shows in the comment, it's a lot like "un-pivoting" the data. Assuming you start off like this:

[image: start]

The following routine ought to do the trick:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeconstructData()

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim CountryArray(100) As String
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, _
    RowIndex As Long, ColIndex As Long, _
    TargetCounter As Long

'assign sheets and variables up-front for easy reference
TargetCounter = 1
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set OutSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
LastRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

'error trap
If LastCol > 100 Then
    MsgBox ("Script designed for a max of 100 countries, exiting sub...")
    Exit Sub
End If

'fill up the Country array with the name in [Index, 1] and the position in [Index, 2]
For ColIndex = 2 To LastCol
    CountryArray(ColIndex - 1) = DataSheet.Cells(1, ColIndex).Value
Next ColIndex

'set the headers on our target sheet
OutSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Date"
OutSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Country"
OutSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "Downloads"

'loop through rows on data sheet
For RowIndex = 2 To LastRow

    'loop through columns on data sheet
    For ColIndex = 2 To LastCol
        OutSheet.Cells(TargetCounter + 1, 1) = DataSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 1)
        OutSheet.Cells(TargetCounter + 1, 2) = CountryArray(ColIndex - 1)
        OutSheet.Cells(TargetCounter + 1, 3) = DataSheet.Cells(RowIndex, ColIndex)
        TargetCounter = TargetCounter + 1
    Next ColIndex

Next RowIndex

'set the A column on the out sheet to be of date format
OutSheet.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

'let the user know the script is complete
MsgBox ("Transformation complete!")

End Sub
```

Which will result in this:

[image: end]